# Embedded computer vision platforms

Tags: iphone, android, computer-vision, windows-phone-7

I am planning to start a computer vision based project on a smart phone platform.

I know [iPhone](http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en) and [Andriod](http://github.com/billmccord/OpenCV-Android) have openCV support. I am interested in knowing how was your experience with the level of integration, support and ease of building good apps on either platform.

Also I do want to consider windows phone 7 ( and Zune) as a platform, Are there any Computer Vision libraries for that platform or any good development tools( does Aforgenet work or any other good suggestion) ?

Also can you suggest some popular augmented reality apps which uses cutting edge technology (I am aware of [Pranav Mistry's SixthSense](http://www.pranavmistry.com/projects/sixthsense/))

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10193820/90475) for Silverlight library for AR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately on Windows Phone 7 there is no access to the camera's data stream currently. Instead you are limited to launching the camera app, letting the user take a picture, then receiving that picture data.

This is a much requested feature so could change at any time.

Comment: I do agree , Launchers and Choosers is very restrictive. Also another major issue is that we are limited the silverlight System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap so access pixel data is very naive! It would be easier if I could upload the image, perform the task over the cloud and return the image to keep my work easy!

Comment: Argh - thats so annoying. I thought WP7 was supposed to be super polished! Not having access to a real-time stream of bitmap images as seen by the camera really limits your computer vision options. You can do noise reduction and best-fit selection etc if you have a series of similar images.
@egon Yes there ought to not reason why you couldn't compress the bitmap and then send it to a webservice (WCF or other) for processing. It's just code after all.

Comment: I agree entirely. But best end user experience is possible if everything works on the embedded device, with or without network connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [WordLens](http://questvisual.com/) for cutting edge AR.

Answer (score 0):

I've built AR and other computer vision apps on iOS using OpenCV and found it to be a solid platform. If nothing else, it provides you with a fast, robust set of libraries for Matrix mathematics as well as optimised versions of some of the more common vision algorithms from feature extraction to 3D reconstruction. It's pretty much a defacto standard so there's a great support community out there too and I'd definitely recommend it.

From a development point of view, I tend to write command line OpenCV apps on my Mac and then, when debugged and running, I look at moving them to iOS. This shortens the test/debug cycle (as I don't have to worry about deploying and debugging under iOS) as well as allowing me to focus on the problem at hand rather than vagaries of the mobile device.

It also makes it straightforward to move on to Android platforms though I've found the Java wrappers for OpenCV on Android to be less great. Again however, focus on getting your core algorithm and processing pipeline working on the desktop in (say) C++, then moving it to a mobile device  wrapping in the necessary native code format.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you will use deep learning If yes you need to optimize everything like deep learning networks to smaller networks, mobile dl frameworks such as Tensorflow lite, etc.

You also need to consider the inference time depending on the hardware