# Is there a computer vision library available on Windows Phone 7.x?

Tags: windows-phone-7, computer-vision

It's generally [disallowed to install and use unmanaged applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2010/03/13/windows-phone-7-series-programming-model.aspx) and/or libraries on Windows Phone.

Even though there are builds of [OpenCV targeting ARM](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Building_OpenCV_for_ARM_Cortex-A8), is there an effort to build a Computer Vision library to run under a managed environment provided by Microsoft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try out the Silverlight Augmented Reality Toolkit:

http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/

This works for WP7.